# PHP curl_init load ballance multiple servers

Tags: php, rest, curl

I've got a service that is calling a REST server. I'm using CURL to make the request. We have three endpoints to use for distributing the load. I could create some basic logic that would "randomly" pick an end point but that doesn't seem like a "good" solution. I'm wondering if there is a better solution?

```
define ("REST_SERVER", "http://myService.myCompany.com:8280");
...
$url = REST_SERVER.URL_SIGN;
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-Type: application/json',
  'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);
$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Using an *actual* load balancer on your server?

Comment: I would say your "client" code (= the one consuming the REST API) shouldn't do the load balancing, your endpoint should do it... If you don't feel like doing this, then your idea is not that bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a poor-man's load balancer, you'd enumerate your endpoints into an array, call shuffle() and array_pop() the lucky winner.

```
<?php
$endpoints = array(
   'http://api1.myco.com',
   'http://api2.myco.com'
);

shuffle($endpoints);

define('REST_SERVER', array_pop($endpoints));

// ...
?>
```

I'd also suggest you vet each candidate to ensure it's "up"/"available" before issuing API calls, which is outside the context of this question.